# Use "cd -" without any output

Tags: bash

How do I run the `cd -` command without echoing out any output?
I tried `cd - 2>&1 /dev/null` but that prints out the destination directory.
The reason for this is that I would like to use it an a bash function and I would prefer to not have the unnecessary output.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
cd - > /dev/null
```

You can also do:

```
cd - > uselessfile
```

This will send the output to the "uselessfile" file instead of to STDOUT.

You can also append instead of creating or overwriting the file.

```
cd - >> uselessfile
```

Answer (score 22):

[@erewok already answered the question](https://superuser.com/a/593697/53590), but I will take a stab at explaining what is actually happening and why you are seeing the behavior that you do.

The problem is with your redirection. You are writing:

```
cd - 2>&1 /dev/null
```

which because redirections can appear anywhere within the command line (you can confirm this yourself with something simple like `echo a b 2>&1 c </etc/fstab d`), after redirections are stripped actually becomes:

```
cd - /dev/null
```

See the problem? You are passing two arguments to `cd`, not one argument and two redirections. Since you can only ever be in one current directory at one time, `cd` only considers its first argument, which in this case is the `-`.

What you probably *intended* to write is a `cd` command with redirection of both stderr and stdout to /dev/null. There are two ways to do that.

The easiest in your case would be to simply inform the shell that you want redirection, by adding a `>` character. This is what @erewok is suggesting.

```
cd - 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

This first redirects stderr (file descriptor 2) into file descriptor 1 (stdout), then redirects stdout (implicit 1) into /dev/null. Note that the ordering is important; you won't get the same result if you reverse the redirections, though in some cases it may appear that you do because of how the particular program uses the respective output streams.

Alternatively, as has been suggested by [@demure](https://superuser.com/a/593781/53590), you can use `&>` to redirect both streams at once if this syntax is supported by your shell.

```
cd - &>/dev/null
```

**Do note** that any of these alternatives will also silence the error when `$OLDPWD` no longer exists, since you are redirecting standard error output into the system black hole. If this is a concern, I would check `$?` afterwards; you should confirm this yourself if it is a real concern, but at least in my tests, a failed `cd` (whether `cd $someplace` or `cd -`) sets `$? = 1` while after success `$? = 0`.

Answer (score 11):

You can use:

```
cd ~-
```

According to the bash man page under `Tilde Expansion`:

> If the tilde-prefix is a `~-', the value of the shell variable OLDPWD, if it is set, is substituted.

Comment: Weird but correct answer (for zsh too).

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you can use

```
cd $OLDPWD
```

but in this case you'll need more typing :)

But you'll have an advantage: if there is any error the message will not redirect into /dev/null.

Comment: If `$OLDPWD` is unset, this will drop you in `~`. `cd -` will print an error (and presumably leave you where you already were).

Comment: You haven't right. If $OLDPWD is unset (why? maybe the user can unset this), the 'cd -' has same result as "cd $OLDPWD". Check the manual page ('cd -' is equivalent 'cd "$OLDPWD" && pwd'). Or you can test it :) 'OLDPWD="" ; cd -' - see you'll drop into ~ and print a ~ character.

Comment: I just tested it. On my system, the sequence `cd /tmp` `bash` `cd -` says `bash: cd: OLDPWD not set` at the second cd; whereas the sequence `cd /tmp` `bash` `cd $OLDPWD` drops you into ~ (almost certainly because $OLDPWD expands to an empty string). `cd $OLDPWD` will work fine once you have done at least one `cd` within the shell in question, but not before then.

Comment: Hm, yes, you've right. I've tested with zsh and with zsh doesn't drop error message.

Answer (score 3):

Redirect stdout and stderr:
`cd - &>/dev/null`

the `&>` is the short hand version of `cd - 2>/dev/null 1>&2`, which I what I think you meant to use...

- Note `&>` needs bash >= 4.0.

Ps. most commands can be pointed at locations, so it is unlikely you actually need to `cd`